# Select Rows with a Substring that Lacks a Certain Prefix

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a nvarchar column. I want to select rows where that column includes a certain word, but only if it is not preceded by another word. Example data:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Phrase nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (N'Jeffie likes big cookies.'),
    (N'Good cookies can be made with chocolate.'),
    (N'Maggie likes big cookies and little cookies.')
```

The query should return rows where 'cookies' appears if it is not immediately preceded by 'big'. For the above data, the query should return the first and third rows. The third row is the problem, because 'cookies' appears twice and is only preceded by 'big' once. The closest I have gotten is the following query, but it isn't quite right:

```
SELECT * FROM @T 
WHERE Phrase LIKE N'%cookies%'
AND Phrase NOT LIKE N'%big cookies%'
```

The problem with this query is that it returns only the first row, and I want it to return both the first row and the third row. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Your statement and requirement are not matching. How can you get first row if you dont want rows where you have only "big cookies" in it. I think you need 2nd and 3rd row. Pls confirm.

Comment: Yes, sorry for misstating this. The 2nd and 3rd row are what I want. Thanks for catching the mistake.

Comment: No problem :) Have u tried the simple solution i gave. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this simple solution -**

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE ( Phrase nvarchar(50) )

INSERT INTO @T VALUES 
  (N'Jeffie likes big cookies.')
, (N'Good cookies can be made with chocolate.')
, (N'Maggie likes big cookies and little cookies.'),
(N'big I am here cookies and little cookies.'),
(N'anything here'),
(N'Maggie likes big cakes and little cookies'),
(N'big cookies big cookies')

SELECT * FROM @T where CHARINDEX ('cookies' , REPLACE(Phrase,'big cookies','xxx'))  >0
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Phrase
--------------------------------------------------
Good cookies can be made with chocolate.
Maggie likes big cookies and little cookies.
big I am here cookies and little cookies.
Maggie likes big cakes and little cookies

(4 rows affected)
```

Comment: Thanks, Pawan! This works as well as the other solution but is simpler, so I've marked it as the answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

try This Approach

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Phrase nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES 
(N'Jeffie likes big cookies.'),
(N'Good cookies can be made with chocolate.'),
(N'Maggie likes big cookies and little cookies.')


SELECT 
    *
    FROM @T
       WHERE (LEN(Phrase)-LEN(REPLACE(Phrase,'Big Cookies','')))/LEN('Big Cookies') 
       <> (LEN(Phrase)-LEN(REPLACE(Phrase,'cookies','')))/LEN('cookies')
```

My Result

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this fail with something like `Maggie likes big cakes and little cookies.`

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I've updated the answer to fix this issue

Comment: Thanks Jayasurya, this is clever and works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM @T 
WHERE Phrase LIKE N'%big cookies%'
AND charindex('cookies',Phrase) > 0
```

The order of execution of WHERE clause will check the first condition with 'big cookies' and then it will solve the purpose because of AND.

Comment: Record - Maggie likes big cakes and little cookies will be filtered from your query.

Comment: But in that case, cookies is not preceeded with 'big'.. As you said that you need first and last row, means you need only those sentences which has 'big' followed by 'cookies'. Is that understanding wrong?

Comment: As i understand from the author he needs 2nd and row but in statements he mentioned 1st and 3rd row. He created the confusion. -)

Comment: Hi Anil, Pawan is correct, there was a misstatement in my original question about which rows should be returned. So this isn't exactly the solution I'm looking for, but I have you an upvote (which you can't see because my reputation is too low). Thanks for your help!